# Passive audio phase shifter (180°) - can it be done?

Tags: audio, passive-networks, phase-shift

I understand that most analog hardware phase shifting circuits seem to use OpAmps to get their job done.
I am trying to build a tiny, non-powered in-line adapter for Mp3-players and such to quickly sum up multiple signals - which can easily be accomplished without external power using just resistor signal mixing.
However, to make this adapter really nifty and interesting, a phase shifting switch would really make the icing on the cake.
Now, this leads me to the question in the title of this thread:
a passive audio phase shifter/inverter - can this be done?

Any input/idea/feedback/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really want a phase shifter or do you actually want a signal inverter?

Comment: 180 degrees phase shift independent of frequency pretty much implies an inverter. Dead easy. 1:1 transformer and DPDT switch. (Or centre-tapped secondary and a single pole switch (per channel).

Comment: You really need to specify exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not so clear to me what you want I can point you to something that might help. 
Old telephones used a passive device, a transformer, to separate the incoming signal from the outgoing signal (so that your own voice is suppressed while you're speaking on your phone).
This is a schematic of a T65 made by Ericsson. Almost everyone in the Netherlands had such a phone in the 1970's ;-)

[image: T65 schematic]

What is interesting is that the signal from the Microphone is fed into the transformer in-phase and in anti-phase. So you should not hear yourself on your own speaker. The same transformer also puts the signal on the phone line.

Comment: sorry, everyone, now I feel pretty dumb here; ich was thinking of how delays originating from latency and how this can cause phase shifting, but of course, you are absolutely right, what I am looking for is a phase inverter, not a phase shifter! apologies for that.
let's reformulate the question as follows:
if i sum up multiple audio sources using only resistors and some phase shifting occurs - will a simple polarity-swap solve the problem or would this affect the-output-volume significantly?

Comment: Phase-shifting will not occur when you sum up multiple signals with resistors ! For phase-shifting of a signal you need a delay (at a certain frequency a phase shift corresponds to a certain time-delay). Only when you want 180 degrees phase shift for all frequencies it is the same as inversion = polarity swap = multiply by -1. The 2 are different things and not interchangeable !  So you can combine audio signals with resistors but don't worry/think about phase shifting etc. What you get out is simply an average of all combined signals.